# How can I deploy my Pytorch model into IOS?

Tags: xcode, pytorch

I have a deep learning neural network I built on Pytorch I am seeking to deploy onto IOS.

Answer (score 1):

Native support doesn't exist still I think, but what some do is to export the ONNX model and then open this in Caffe2 which has the support for IOS device (also Androids)

So use [ONNX export tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_caffe2.html) and this [mobile integration helper](https://caffe2.ai/docs/mobile-integration.html).

There is also a path [converting ONNX to CoreML](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/ONNXLive.html#convert-the-onnx-models-to-coreml-models) but depending on your project it may not be super fast.

There is also an option to port the ONNX to TensorFlow Lite and to [integrate](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ios) with your Swift or Objective C app from there on.